# Python: response to the browser then continue to delete files

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have one web based python tool, which is used for building the softwares using SVN checkout.

I have delete the record once the checkout and testing done. While deleting the record it has to delete all the checkout files along with DB rows. But those checkouts are very big (in GBs) So when I click on delete in browser it first deletes the rows in DB tables, but for file delete takes more time almost 1 to 2 mins. I have tried `threading` call after delete the database return to browser and proceed for deleting the files. But it doesn't help.

I tried the below code:

```
import threading

def data_delete(inputs):

    # call function to take delete the database rows 
    deleteDataBaseRows_function(inputs)

    id1 = 1
    id2 = 2
    # call the maintainence_function here
    t = threading.Thread(target=deletefiles_function, args=[id1, id2])
    # setDaemon=False to stop the thread after complete
    t.setDaemon(False)
    # starting the thread
    t.start()

    # return response/anything-else you want to return
    return "it worked"


def deleteDataBaseRows_function(inputs):
    # deleting the database process here
    print "table rows deleted"
def deletefiles_function(id1, id2):
    print "Files are deleted"

res = profile_update("inputs")
print res
```

I got the below output:

```
table rows deleted
Files are deleted
response to the browser
```

But My expected behavior is after delete the database rows, the User should proceed with other work on the browser tool (otherwise he has wait until he completes the entire file deletion), in backend the files start deleting it.

```
table rows deleted
response to the browser
Files are deleted
```

Comment: It could just because the files get deleted very quickly.

Comment: @martineau I think you are right. The above code was just to check the return statement with thread. But I didnt add wait time in `deletefiles_function`. when i added 1 min delay it works as I expected. Thank you